# Is there a way of assigning an int number to different instances of stateless services?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I'm building a solution where we'll have a (service-fabric) stateless service deployed to K instances. This service is tasked with some workload (like querying) and I want to split the workload between them as evenly as I can - and I want to make this a dynamic solution, which means if I decide to go from K instances to N instances tomorrow, I want the workload splitting to happen in a way that it will automatically distribute the load across N instances now. I don't have any partitions specified for this service.

As an example -

Let's say I'd like to query a database to retrieve a particular chunk of the records. I have 5 nodes. I want these 5 nodes to retrieve different 1/5th of the set of records. This can be achieved through some query logic like (row_id % N == K) where N is the total number of instances and K is the unique `instance_number`.

I was hoping to leverage `FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().NodeId` - but this returns a guid which is not overly useful.

I'm looking for a way where I can deterministically say it's instance number M out of N (I need to be able to name the instances through 1..N) - so I can set my querying logic according to this. One of the requirements is if that instance goes down / crashes etc... when SF automatically restarts it, it should still identify as the same instance id - so that 2 or more nodes doesn't query the same set of results.

What is the best of solving this problem? Is there a solution which involves pure configuration through `ApplicationManifest.xml` or `ServiceManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no out of the box solution for your problem**, but it can be easily done in many different ways.

The simplest way is using the [Queue-Based Load Leveling pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/queue-based-load-leveling) in conjunction with [Competing Consumers pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers). 
It consists of **creating a queue**, add the work to the queue, and each instance get one message to process this work, if one instance goes down and the message is not processed, it goes back to the queue and another instance pick it up.

This way you don't have to worry about the number of instances running, failures and so on.

Regarding the work being put in the queue, it will depend if you want to to do batch processing or process item by item.

**Item by item**, you put one message in the queue for each item being processed, this is a simple way to handle the work and each instance process one message at time, or multiple messages in parallel.

**In batch**, you can put a message that represents a list of items to be processed and each instance process that batch until completed, this is a bit trickier because you might have to handle the progress of the work being done, in case of failure, the next time you can continue from where it stopped.

The queue approach is a reactive design, in this case the work need to be put in the queue to trigger the processing, If you want a proactive approach and need to keep track of which work goes to who, you probably might be better of using some other approach, like a [Leasing mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob), where each instance acquire a lease that belongs to the instance until it releases the lease, this would more suitable when you work with partitioned data or other mechanism where you can easily split the load.

Regarding the issue with the ID, an option would be the [InstanceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.statelessservicecontext.instanceid?view=azure-dotnet) of the replica you are on, you can reach by `StatelessService.Context.InstanceId`, it is not a sequential ID, but it is a random number. It is better than using the node id, because you might have multiple partitions on same node and the id would conflict with each other.
If you decide to use named partitions, you could use order in the partition name instead, so each partition would have a sequential name.

Worth mention that service fabric has a limitation that **[doesn't allow services to have multiple replicas on same node](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/325)**, because of this limitation you might have to design your services with this in mind, otherwise you won't be able to scale out once the limit is reached. Also, the same thread has some discussion about approaches to process multiple distributed items that might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Diego! Do you mind adding documentation on named partitions because it looks like we might be able to name the partitions and at least use those names to deduce 1..N. I'm aware of the Q / CC patterns - which was the original plan but because of some additional constraints I'm not choosing to move with those, but rather with this design.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no documentation for that, the best you can find is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricservice?view=azureservicefabricps). It is as simple as this command: 
`Update-ServiceFabricService -Stateless -ServiceName "fabric:/app/service" -PartitionNamesToAdd "1","2","3"`